# WordPress Issue: Problem Arises When Navigating to Other Pages

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.img[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIKx7.jpg)ur.com/BilH3.jpg)
Upon navigating to another page on a WordPress site, the theme momentarily ceases to function correctly on the page. Please take a look at the problem; I have included two images - one showcasing the issue and the other displaying the site on a static image.

Comment: What do you mean by « momentarily ceases to function correctly »? Sometimes? Or all the time?

Comment: What is the name of the theme? Any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Can you post the code? Orherwise no-one can help you…

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.